# Monitoring Linux performance events for cgroups

Tags: linux, perf

I am currently trying to monitor some hardware events of my system (6 hardware counters and 24 CPUs) as well as its cgroups. I take here the example of the LLC loads and cpu-cycles events.

To this end I use the `perf` command.

However, when considering an idle cgroup (actually corresponding to a docker container only running bash) and running `perf` for either cgroups or system wide monitoring, it seems that I am getting approximatly the same number of cpu-cycles in both cases:

```
$ sudo perf stat  -e LLC-loads,cpu-cycles -a sleep 60
$ sudo perf stat -e instructions,cpu-cycles   --cgroup=docker/b1cd988201789e55128393cff5ffbf37b0d6efec0fc70e1b716163b4b1f91f1f -a sleep 60
```

I was expecting a way smaller number of cpu cycles for my cgroups. (Same results are obtained when providing either the `--cpu=0-23` or the `-a` option.)

Am I missing something here?

I am wondering how the `--cgroup` option works. In the end, is it only configured for some events?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the answer in the documentation, which is not clear :

> -G name, --cgroup name monitor only in the container (cgroup) called "name". This option is available only in per-cpu mode. The cgroup
>   filesystem must be mounted. All threads belonging to container "name"
>   are monitored when they run on the monitored CPUs. Multiple cgroups
>   can be provided. Each cgroup is applied to the corresponding event,
>   i.e., first cgroup to first event, second cgroup to second event and
>   so on. It is possible to provide an empty cgroup (monitor all the
>   time) using, e.g., -G foo,,bar. Cgroups must have corresponding
>   events, i.e., they always refer to events defined earlier on the
>   command line.

And it actually means that in order to get several events from 1 cgroups in the same perf command, I should list the name of that cgroup as many times as the number of events.

EDIT example (long container IDs must be used, but here I use short IDs for clarity):

```
sudo perf stat -e instructions,cpu-cycles,LLC-loads   --cgroup=docker/b1cd,docker/b1cd,docker/b1cd -a sleep 60
```

Comment: Can you show example of perf command with correct usage for cgroup (add it to the answer or as comment)?

Comment: You may want to hightlight the 1:1 mapping relationship of event in event list and cgroup in the cgroup list :-)

Comment: Is it possible to automatically terminate the `perf stat`  after the container is stopped/removed/killed? I'd like to gather statistics about my container, but the runtime can be anything bettween 1 minute and 2 hours, so I cannot use the sleep command. Thanks!

Comment: I would run a script killing the perf command with the corresponding container ID, as soon as the container is stopped. But this is off topic.