# perf monitors the docker container not counted

Tags: docker, perf

I want to use the perf to monitor the docker container with:

```
$sudo perf stat -e cycles -a -I 1000 -o out.txt --cgroup=docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95 sleep 5
```

however, it can not count the cycles in out.txt:

```
 1 # started on Thu Jun  7 22:49:34 2018
  2 
  3 #           time             counts unit events
  4      1.000224074      <not counted>      cycles                    docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
  5      2.000515835      <not counted>      cycles                    docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
  6      3.000805321      <not counted>      cycles                    docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
  7      4.001008437      <not counted>      cycles                    docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
  8      5.001234875      <not counted>      cycles                    docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
```

And monitoring multi-events such as:

```
$sudo perf stat -e cycles,instructions -a -I 1000 -o out2.txt --cgroup=docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95,docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95 sleep 5
```

Got the same result in out2.txt:

```
  1 # started on Thu Jun  7 23:23:15 2018
  2 
  3 #           time             counts unit events
  4      1.000326390      <not counted>      cycles                    docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
  5      1.000326390      <not counted>      instructions              docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
  6      2.000665181      <not counted>      cycles                    docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
  7      2.000665181      <not counted>      instructions              docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
  8      3.000979419      <not counted>      cycles                    docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
  9      3.000979419      <not counted>      instructions              docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
 10      4.001281621      <not counted>      cycles                    docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
 11      4.001281621      <not counted>      instructions              docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
 12      5.001233401      <not counted>      cycles                    docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
 13      5.001233401      <not counted>      instructions              docker/c04e4686d0195f9863112983e472ec7b519642bf4cfd3856f327d02e05047f95
```

How to count the cycles for docker container?

I have look at [Monitoring Linux performance events for cgroups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473963/monitoring-linux-performance-events-for-cgroups) and [kubelet fails to get cgroup stats for docker and kubelet services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726216/kubelet-fails-to-get-cgroup-stats-for-docker-and-kubelet-services).

Answer (score 0):

It is unsuitable for using `--cgroup=`. I should profile the process ID with `-p` to monitor a specific process.